# Regex match string not starting with

Tags: regex

I want to find matches for string `example` but not `www.example`. What is the regex I can use? I've tried the following but it doesn't work:

`(?!www.\)example`

Comment: Could just use `/^example$/`  to only catch example

Comment: Check this [^www.]example

Comment: `[^www\.]example` matches `"example` in `alt="example.com"`. Note it matches the starting quote.

Comment: @dwij: no it's wrong, you didn't well understand character classes.

Comment: @CasimiretHippolyte yeah, it is enough to have one w in that case. am I right?

Comment: @dwij: yes, character classes are only sets of characters, so `[^.w]`, `[^w.]` and `[^www.]` are the same character class.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you just try to match a string that does start with `example` but not with `www.example` than it would be as easy as:

```
^example
```

Otherwise you can use a negative lookbehind:

```
(?<!\bwww\.)\bexample\b
```

The `\b` in here is a word boundery, meaning that it matches it, as long as it is not part of a string. (In other words if it isn't followed by or following any A-Za-z characters, a number or an underscore.)

As mentioned by @CasimiretHippolyte this **does** still match strings like `www.othersubdomain.example.com`.

**[Example](https://regex101.com/r/V8kp7N/2)**

Comment: `(?<!www\.)example` So I tried everywhich way but I had no clue what `<` stands for. Would really appreciate what it does. I understand `^` is to match the begining and I left it out because I wanted to match in the middle of the paragraph as well. `()` is a capture group. `?!` is a negative lookahead? No clue about `<`. Thanks again.

Comment: @ShivanandSharma [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2973495/479156) goes in a bit deeper into the positive/negative lookahead/lookbehind if you want to get some good examples.

Comment: This answer doesn't make sense. `^` and `(?<!www)` are zero-width assertions and checks the same position. You can't have the start of the string `^` and *not preceded by "www"* at the same time! `^example` produces exactly the same result, `(?<!www)` is useless (as an aside `(?<!www\.)` makes more sense but is useless too with the `^` anchor). `(?<!\bwww\.)example\b` is probably the right answer.

Comment: @CasimiretHippolyte You are right. I got thrown off by the `(?<!www)example` variant still matching the start of the string because I simply forgot the `\.`. Do you suggest I delete the answer or should I modify it to either `(?<!www\.)example` or your example?

Comment: `(?<!www\.)example` is a more correct answer, but it doesn't match something like `abcwww.example.com` or `exampleabc.com`. That's why I suggested to add word boundaries. However `(?<!\bwww\.)\bexample\b` matches something like `www.othersubdomain.example.com`. It isn't so simple.

Comment: @CasimiretHippolyte I've updated by answer to make it at least a bit better. Thanks for pointing it out.